# While unit testing REST endpoint, LocalDateTime is sent truncated

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, junit

I'd like to unit test my REST endpoint. I'm  very new to this, but I was able to write the following code:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/myrest");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String empJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(clientDto);
StringEntity input = new StringEntity(empJson);
input.setContentType("application/json");
request.setEntity(input);
org.apache.http.HttpResponse httpResponse = 
HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
```

`clientDto` is an instance of a simple POJO with a field of type `LocalDateTime`. The thing is that my deserializer always gets that date as the following string `{` (one char only). How do I fix this? If you think that unit testing can be done in a better way, please let me know. I've used Apache dependency but this is not a must.

Comment: Show a complete example. What's the point of telling us about the class of clientDto rather than just showing the code that gives its type and the class it is? Also show a minimal example. You have a problem with the way your dates are serialized to JSON. Therefore, your problem has nothing to do with HTTP and DTOs. Remove them from the equation and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RestAssured` library it is very easy to test REST API. Please have a look at this code. One of its pros is that it is self-explanatory.

```
CreditClass dto = new CreditClass();
dto.setCreditGranted(false);

given()
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.body(dto)
.when().post("localhost:8080/rest-api").then()
.statusCode(200)
.body("creditGranted", equalTo(true));
```